# Can't enable TLSv1.2 on nginx on a FreeNAS jail

Tags: nginx, freebsd, truenas

I'm quite new to the FreeBSD environment, I'm quite used to the Linux one.

I've created a jail in FreeNAS 9.3 and installed nginx with ssl support following several online resources (googled "freebsd jail nginx ssl" or something like that) and a lets encrypt certificate. I know there's a newer FreeNAS version based on FreeBSD 10 but I can't upgrade just yet.

Everything works smoothly but my SSLLabs rating is a C because `The server supports only older protocols, but not the current best TLS 1.2. Grade capped to C.`

In my nginx config file TLSv1.2 is enabled and the server reload gives no error:

```
[...]
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    #SSL
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
    ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4";
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_dhparam /usr/local/etc/ssl/dhparam.pem;
[...]

 # service nginx reload
Performing sanity check on nginx configuration:
nginx: the configuration file /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

Can anybody point me to the error or to a possible workaround? Thankyou

UPDATE:

after kind comments of @Drifter104 and @Amiramix, openssl version is 0.9.8za and doesn't seem to support TLSv1.2

Now that the mistery is solved, I need to discover how to install a more update openssl, thank you

Comment: The version of openssl installed my not support it

Comment: Can you check `openssl version` to get the version of OpenSSL? TLS 1.2 is supported in version 1.0.1: https://www.openssl.org/docs/faq.html Did you read the nginx document http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html ? Also, `openssl ciphers -v` will give you list of available ciphers in OpenSSL, you can check if the ciphers you wanted to enable are supported.

Comment: ok, both of you are right: OpenSSL 0.9.8za-freebsd 5 Jun 2014 and supported ciphers are SSLv2 and SSLv3...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original question has already been answered  in the comments.

OpenSSL 0.9.8za-freebsd has no support for TLS 1.2

According to freshports, you can upgrade openssl from the port coolection (eg using pkg or portmaster).

https://www.freshports.org/security/openssl/